# Automorphism group of compact almost complex manifold

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, lie-groups, complex-manifolds

Does the automorphism group of a compact almost complex manifold carry a (canonical) Lie group structure? Part 3 of Theorem 4.1 in
*"The automorphism group of a homogeneous almost complex manifold" by J. Wolf ([link at AMS site](https://www.ams.org/journals/tran/1969-144-00/S0002-9947-1969-0256300-9/S0002-9947-1969-0256300-9.pdf)) says that in a specific group-invariant setting the automorphism group is compact if and only if the almost complex structure is not integrable. Is this a general phenomenon?

Comment: You have misstated Wolf's result.  What he shows is that, in the 'irreducible' case (appropriately defined), the  automorphism group of a compact homogeneous almost-complex manifold is compact if and only if the almost-complex structure is NOT integrable.  For example, the automorphism group of $\mathbb{CP}^n$ is not compact while the almost-complex automorphism group of  the non-integrable $S^6=\mathrm{G}_2/\mathrm{SU}(3)$ is compact.

Comment: Thanks, I have made an edit to change the statement

Answer (score 8):

See Kobayashi, **Transformation Groups**, Theorem 4.1 page 16, where the theorem is proved that the group of automorphisms of a smooth compact almost complex manifold is a finite dimensional Lie group acting smoothly.

Comment: Clearly a product like $\mathbb{CP}^n\times S^6$, with the product almost complex structure coming from the usual complex structure on $\mathbb{CP}^n$, has noncompact automorphism group, is homogeneous, and not a complex manifold. So noncompact automorphism group is not enough to ensure integrability.

Comment: That's why 'irreducible' is so important in Wolf's result.

Comment: Good point, in the general case we should at least add the irreducibility assumption that the almost complex manifold is not a (non-trivial) product of two other almost complex structures